# How to pass a dropdown selected value through jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my code. I want the jQuery code to pass the select box value to be sent on specific url on selection without refreshing the page so that I can use that value in query on specific page.

```html
<?php include "datalink.php"; ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
    <script>  
    $(function() {  
   $( "#q" ).autocomplete({
     source: "dropdown.php",
     minLength: 2,
     select: function(event,ui){
    $("#qid").val(ui.item.id);
    }
    });

 
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      collapsible: true
    });
   });

function validatebankForm() {
   var x = document.getElementById("qid").value;
   if(x == 'null')
   {
    alert('Please select an option from list');
    return false;
   }   
}
</script>
 <style>
  .ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-align:left;
  }
  /* IE 6 doesn't support max-height
   * we use height instead, but this forces the menu to always be this tall
   */
  * html .ui-autocomplete {
    height: 100px;
  }
  .ui-autocomplete.ui-widget {
   font-size: 11px;
   }
  .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {font-size:12px !important; font-weight:bold;}
   #tabs-1{font-size: 12px !important;}
     
  </style>
  <div id="tabs">
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>    
<table width="100%" style="text-align:center;"><tr><td>
<form action="search.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <?php
  $query = "SELECT distinct area FROM goa"; 
  $result = mysql_query($query); 
  ?>
  <select   name="area" id="area" style="width:180px; max-width:90%;"> <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?> 
  <option name="area" id="area" value="<?php echo $line['area'];?>"> <?php echo $line['area'];?> </option>  
  <?php } ?> 
  </select>

  <input  type="text" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue" onclick="if (this.defaultValue==this.value) this.value=''" name="q" id="q" placeholder="Search Company | Service | Product...." style="width:300px; max-width:90%;">
<input type="hidden" id="qid" name="qid" value="null">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</td></tr></table>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does `console.log(ui.item.id)` prints in `select` ... it must be the value you selected... you can make an AJAX call there

Comment: As said before, the correct way to go would be Ajax. But I'd like to see what you've tried yourself before you ask us to help you. Stack Overflow is a website for programmers and enthusiasts to help eachother out when needed. It's not a free resource to get programmers to do your job for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize you form and make a POST request using AJAX:

```
$("form").submit(function( event ) { 
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "url",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            //something         
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: what will  be the php code to fetch the data .....on the requried page url.....eg ....$x=$_post['value'];....i want to store the fetch data in variable so that i can use it query....

Comment: @Preetam Your `select` name is "area". So on target php page you can access the value with: `$area = $_POST['area'];`

Comment: here is my script ....... 

$(document).ready(function () {
 
  $("area").submit(function( event ) { 
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "dropdown.php",
        data: { id1: id },
              success: function(data) {
                     $("#area").html(data);
            }
    });

 
 
 
 
    return false;
}
 
 
});



<?php
   $a =$_POST['id1'];
   echo $a ;
   ?>
but i getting an error.............Undefined index: id1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\E\box.php on line 2

Comment: i dint found any errors for this script in console......
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('area').submit(function( event ) 
{ 
var data = $(this).serialize(); 
$.ajax({ 
type: 'POST', 
dataType: 'json', 
url: 'box.php', 
data: ({ id1: id }),
 success: function(data) 
 { 
 $('#area').html(data); 
}
 });
 return false; 
 });
 });
</script>

Comment: actually i want to create the search box where it has the dropdown which defines location of the place and other one for inputing the text which has autocomplete feature....it should work in such way that ..suppose i have selected one location in drop down and if i typed any on input box it should only show those autocomplete data which comes under selected location ....not the all data.....

Answer (score -1):

Try using `Ajax` with `jquery`. Here is some documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Please note that `mysql` is not longer supported. Try using `PDO` or `mysqli` instead

Comment: Although this is a correct point into the right direction, this is NOT an answer to the users question. Therefor this should be a comment instead.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, i don't think the question was really specific. I thought that he wanted to know how to do it. As he has obviously not searched for it or tried something himself in that direction.

Comment: There's no need to appologize. I prefer to see you trying and make mistakes instead of doing nothing at all. I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer. I simply gave you an explanation of what was wrong with it so you can improve.